# Como posso pegar o caminho do Input file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input, phpmailer

Preciso enviar vários anexos  via PHPmailer e estou usando jQuery para pegar o valor do `input file`, agora eu preciso pegar o caminho do arquivo para poder enviar por e-mail, porém quando eu pego o caminho ele vem com `C:\fakepath\image.jpg` ou somente `image.jpg`, andei pesquisando e isso e relacionado a segurança dos navegadores, então como vocês enviam anexos? o esquema que eu estou fazendo e o seguinte:

HTML

```
       <div class="divAnexos">
           <label for="anexos" class="label">Anexos:</label> &nbsp;
           <input type="file" id="pegarAnexo" multiple>
           <textarea id="anexos"></textarea>
           <button id="addAnexos" class="ui-state-default"> Anexar </button>
        </div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('addAnexos').onclick = function () {
      document.getElementById('pegarAnexo').click();
   };
  $('#pegarAnexo').change(function (event) {
      tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      console.log(tmppath);
      $('#anexos').html($(this).val());
   });
```

PHP

```
function enviarEmail($aUser, $aPass, $aPort, $aDestinatario, $aHost, $aAssunto, $aCorpo, $aArquivos = '', $aCopia = '') {

   $mail = new PHPMailer;
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
   $mail->Host = $aHost;
   $mail->Port = $aPort;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->Username = $aUser;
   $mail->Password = $aPass;
   $mail->setFrom($aUser);
   $mail->addAddress($aDestinatario);
   $mail->addAddress($aCopia);
   $mail->Subject = $aAssunto;
   $mail->Body = $aCorpo;
   $mail->addAttachment($aArquivos);

   if (!$mail->send()) {
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

O algoritmo faz o seguinte, quando clicar no botão `addAnexos` ele abrirá o `input file` para pegar o arquivo e colocar a informação do caminho no `textarea`, o `tmppath` vem de uma ideia que peguei [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/4FGg8/1/), que pega o caminho temporário do arquivo, porem esse caminho só funciona no Google Chrome e Mozilla.

Comment: Por que você precisa saber o *path* para enviar o arquivo? A intenção é enviar o arquivo e isto o HTML faz por você. Se quiser usar JS para automatizar, ok, mas o *path* não é necessário.

Comment: biggown, como enviar anexos sem a necessidade apenas com html ?  tenho essa dúvida, porque eu passo na função enviarEmail o parametro Arquivo, que contém uma string com o path.

Comment: Que função `enviarEmail`? Não estou vendo nenhuma.

Comment: Você tem que dar uma estudada sobre o campo file, após entender como funciona o upload de arquivos, você conseguirá o caminho físico do arquivo para envia-lo como anexo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Isso não é possível.

Conforme você já leu à respeito está relacionado à segurança e privacidade. Não há meios normais para passar por isto. Só seria possível em uma falha de segurança grave do navegador e certamente não resolve seu objetivo.

Se você quer enviar um arquivo do usuário, ele tem que dizer o que ele quer enviar sem sua interferência como programador. Qualquer informação adicional além do próprio arquivo não é relevante para seu código. Não consigo imaginar qualquer aplicação para isso em um navegador.

Se precisa saber o *path* por alguma outra razão, não use um navegador como plataforma. Não tem jeito.

## Solução para envio por AJAX

O mais comum é usar soluções prontas. Como você está usando jQuery acho que seria útil ver o *plugin* [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Exemplo da documentação:

```
<form id="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
```

Código p/ uso do *plugin*:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
 
    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/AJAX/jQueryForm.html).

À partir disto você pode ir personalizando de acordo com sua necessidade.

## PHP

O código PHP só tem que receber dados do navegador, ele não precisa saber nada onde o arquivo estava no cliente. Isso é feito com $FILES. Algo assim:

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
```

Pelo código postado provavelmente você já fez isto e está armazenando a lista de arquivos em algum lugar e passa isto pelo parâmetro `$aArquivos`.

O que provavelmente você está tentando fazer é isto:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['seuArquivo']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['seuArquivo']['name']);
```

Isso permite manter um nome "apresentável" para o arquivo quando ele for anexado à mensagem de *e-mail*. Caso contrário o nome usado será o mesmo colocado no diretório de arquivos temporários.